# Web service under Docker connection issue

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I'm having some troubles running Apache under Docker, and I wanted to ask for some directions. My current setup is the following : I have Docker 0.8 installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I want to run an Apache server under Docker, and bind it to a specific ip on the host, my intention being to run multiple Apache servers under Docker on the same hardware node each with it's one interface.

Now, I've been able to start the Apache server inside Docker, and have it run like a daemon (-D FOREGROUND, or under supervisord), and I've even been able to bind it to 0.0.0.0:$PORT and access it from the outside. But when I created multiple interfaces on the hardware node let's say 10.10.10.1, and 10.10.10.2, and tried to bind to -p 10.10.10.1:80:80, I'm not able to access 10.10.10.1:80 from the outside.

A little info about the network setup: I have my eth0 interface which has trunking out of which I create multiple vlans on which I want to put Docker instances (probably with a bridge on the eth0.$VLAN_NO, when I want to put more on the same vlan).

So basically, to reiterate, i have started a Docker container bound with -p 10.10.10.1:80:80, with an Apache inside Docker on port 80 and I can't access it (although binded on 0.0.0.0:80:80 works).

Comment: The simple answer for this is pipework. It doesn't do exactly what I initially wanted but it's still ok. I'll post an more detailed answer.